# Select last 7 days from unix timestamp mysql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have never really messed with this type of query so I need some assistance. I have a table with a `timestamp` column that contains the following

```
1488693506
1488576676
1488575917
1487563577
1487563170
1487352348
1487352291
1487207322
```

I am using the following mysql statement

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (`timestamp` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

From what I have seen this should return the last 7 days of records that are within the last 7 days from the timestamps I listed, but no records are being returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You got any solution ? I have also faced the same where no records are being returned!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `from_unixtime` function to convert the date either to the `where` condition and to see a readable date format:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(`timestamp`) 
  FROM table 
 WHERE from_unixtime(`timestamp`) > date_sub(now(), interval 7 day);
```

It will show you:

```
March, 05 2017 05:58:26
March, 03 2017 21:31:16
March, 03 2017 21:18:37
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d60e91/1

EDIT: Assuming the timestamp is indexed, a more optimal way of writing the same thing might be as follows:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`) x
  FROM test_t 
 WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```